# Responsive CSS Figure/Image Grid

Tags: html, css, image, figure

How would you go about building a responsive image grid with images varying in height and width. The suggested solution will need to be  purely in **CSS** and working in **IE9** and above.

Ideally, the images should respect the width assigned to them, but their heights should be of equal values, until reaching mobile viewports. For mobile viewports, the images will stack as block elements.

For this example I am using a figure element containing an image and a caption related to the image.

Example HTML structure:

```
<div>
  <figure class="landscape">
    <img 
         src="http://placehold.it/750x500/e8117f/ffffff"
         alt=""
         >
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img 
         src="http://placehold.it/300x500/efc63e/ffffff"
         alt=""
         >
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Current HTML and CSS:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/qpvqvLy3/)

**In reference to the image posted below:** *The images with the dimensions 750x500 need to fill the gap outlined with the dashed stroke, to be of equal height to the image with the dimensions of 300x500.*

[image: Image grid reference.]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is with flexbox. The downside is that ie9 does not support flexbox.

```css
/* Body */

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Container */

div {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1050px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}


/* Figure */

figure {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.landscape {
  max-width: 750px;
}

.portrait {
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}

figcaption {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  color: #888;
  font: 12px arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: -4px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  figure {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  figure:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .landscape {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .portrait {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  /* Placeholder */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure class="landscape">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x500/e8117f/ffffff" alt="">
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/efc63e/ffffff" alt="">
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500/efc63e/ffffff" alt="">
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="landscape">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x500/e8117f/ffffff" alt="">
    <figcaption>
      Image Caption
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```